# C# - Operator: ? - Is it possible to pass something or nothing to a function?

Tags: c#

I know that there's other ways to do what I need to do. I just want to know if it can be done.

It's about the question mark that replace a if else.

```
public void doSomething() { ...... }
public void doSomething(int i) { ...... }
public void f(int i)
{
    doSomething( i > 0 ? [NOTHING] : i ); 
}
```

Is there something I can write (intead of [NOTHING]) to pass no parameter to the function and be able to call doSomething() ?

Comment: Can't you just write `i > 0 ? doSomething() : doSomething( i );`.

Comment: @user2296177 `i > 0 ? doSomething() : doSomething( i );` - does this even compile when *doSomething()* is void?

Comment: @user3185569 It does for me.

Comment: @user2296177 Where did you compile this? Because a ternary can only be used where an expression is expected, not as a statement.  This will fail with compile error CS0201.

Comment: @Kyle VC++2015 and GCC5.1

Comment: @user2296177 This question is about C#, not C++.

Comment: @Kyle It was originally tagged C++ as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You should use a standard `if..else` or you could rewrite it this way if `doSomething` returns something.

```
i > 0 ? doSomething() : doSomething(i);
```

The results of the ternary has to be compatible. The method call is baked in by the compiler to know what instruction to jump to. The ternary operator can't rewrite that.

Comment: I don't think this compiles whether the method is void or non void.

Comment: @user3185569 No, it doesn't.